# Jersey 2.12 Maven Artifact Location

Tags: rest, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

Can't seem to find the entries to put in my `pom.xml` for Jersey 2.12 (https://jersey.java.net/download.html).

When I googled it using "Jersey 2.12 Maven" as the keywords, Google returned a package entitled getperka.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.getperka.flatpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatpack-jersey</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this the correct package/lib for Jersey 2.12?

The reason I ask is because I see references for glassfish and grizzly but not for the standard reference implementation. And also, in my current `pom.xml`, I am using 1.18.1 for the following artifacts:

- jersey-client
- jersey-servlet
- jersey-server
- jersey-core
- jersey-json
- jersey-multipart

Does this getperka.flatpack dependency contain all six of these artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

The Jersey 2.x release is found under the [`org.glassfish.jersey`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey/project) archetype group id:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently the release version is 2.11 but read carefully the details on [the page you linked](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) to in your question. There is a way to start playing with Jersey 2.12 by using two maven archetypes:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeVersion=2.12

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.12
```

These should download you the JARs you need. For production applications though, I would recommend working with a release version (currently 2.11).